# Sails.js with a systemd script

Tags: node.js, nginx, sails.js, fedora, systemd

I have managed to get a Sails js application working on a server, currently just running with nohup to keep the service running when the SSH session is ended.

Obviously, this is not a very robust solution. What happens if the app crashes or the server is reset etc? I am using Fedora so I am using systemd.

Here is what I have so far.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/dashboard-app/app.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=dashboard-app
User=***
Group=***
Environment=NODE_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service starts okay but the script does not know about the config files so will default to Sails port 1337. Going to that port on the server will not work either.

I have also got nginx set up to with the port set in the sails config file which works fine but I don't think this will make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `WorkingDirectory=` to the top-level directory of your Node app, wherever that is.

For example:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/dashboard-app
```

or for global-installed apps,

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/lib/node_modules/dashboard-app
```